# default permissible datatype conversion matrix

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, type-conversion, documentation

Today I wanted to define a uuid of value `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. Being a SQL Server man, I'd [usually](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b57d2a81ed82b53cc5231b7d3ce34e3)...

```
select cast(0x0 as uniqueidentifier);
```

...but I'm in postgres world now so I whipped out a [sensible](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=afd916909daffec1f462db08a8feda4d)...

```
select cast('\x00'::bytea as uuid);
```

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type bytea to uuid
LINE 1: select cast('\x00'::bytea as uuid);
               ^
```

Damn! So I head over to the [postgres docs on Type Conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv.html) hoping to see a doc like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine#implicit-and-explicit-conversion) to review which datatypes I can cast between by default without needing to [create an explicit cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html).

[image: sql-server-implicit-explicit-conversion-matrix]

If such a chart does exist in the docs, it's well hidden. Google is likewise not super helpful in this regard.

> Is there a good documentation reference for default permissible type casts in postgresql?

---

<sup>To be clear, I don't actually care about the uuid</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get a list using the `psql` client with

```
\dCS
```

This will show all casts defined between system data types.

In addition, all types can be cast to and from `text` using the type input and output functions.

Answer (score 10):

As a supplement to [Laurenz' post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254253/68127)...

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> `\dC[+] [ pattern ]`
>
> Lists type casts. If pattern is specified, only casts whose source or target types match the pattern are listed. If + is appended to the command name, each object is listed with its associated description.

`\set ECHO_HIDDEN on` reveals `\dCS+` to be executing...

```sql
SELECT pg_catalog.format_type(castsource, NULL) AS "Source type",
       pg_catalog.format_type(casttarget, NULL) AS "Target type",
       CASE WHEN c.castmethod = 'b' THEN '(binary coercible)'
            WHEN c.castmethod = 'i' THEN '(with inout)'
            ELSE p.proname
       END AS "Function",
       CASE WHEN c.castcontext = 'e' THEN 'no'
            WHEN c.castcontext = 'a' THEN 'in assignment'
            ELSE 'yes'
       END AS "Implicit?",
       d.description AS "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_cast c LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     ON c.castfunc = p.oid
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type ts
     ON c.castsource = ts.oid
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns
     ON ns.oid = ts.typnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type tt
     ON c.casttarget = tt.oid
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nt
     ON nt.oid = tt.typnamespace
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description d
     ON d.classoid = c.tableoid AND d.objoid = c.oid AND d.objsubid = 0
WHERE ( (true  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(ts.oid)
) OR (true  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(tt.oid)
) )
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

...which points us to a few more interesting docs pages.

- [`pg_cast`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html) - the base system table listing permissible casts
- [`pg_type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) - the base system table reference for datatypes
- [`format_type()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) - a prettifier function for `pg_type`. Helpful in mapping proper names to aliases as seen on [the datatypes reference table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE)